# Emperor's Helmet not in inventory after spawning it in

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

So I used console commands in Oblivion to spawn in the [Emperor's Helmet](http://uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Emperor%27s_Helmet#Emperor.27s_Helmet), but it isn't showing up in my inventory. It has the weight added but just not the icon to equip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the item you added in the console can not be seen in the inventory, that means that the item was not meant to be used by the player (as answered by @z '). However, you can use the [`player.equipitem <form ID>` console command to force equip it onto your character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfyJr.jpg). (The form ID of the Emperor's Helmet is 1FED2.)

Here's a screenshot of my character with the Emperor's Helmet equipped. Notice that my inventory doesn't show a head apparel equipped nor is the Emperor's Helmet in there:

[image: Using <code>player equipitem <formid></code> console command to equip the Emperor's Helmet.]

If you're willing to use the [Construction Set](http://uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Construction_Set), you can mod items to be player usable (allowing them to shown and be equipped in your inventory) by locating them in the CS and checking the "playable" box.<sup>1</sup>

Source:
<sup>1</sup> [UESP Wiki, 'Other Specialty Gear' talk page post by anonymous user](http://uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion_talk:Other_Specialty_Gear#Emperor.27s_Armor).

Answer (score 7):

Some items aren't meant to be player usable.  Even though you can add it via the console you won't be able to equip it from the inventory menu.  The only thing you can do is use the console to remove it.